# Check constraint on Oracle compare sum to other table value

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using ORACLE 11.2 DB and have 3 Tables:

**PROJECT_EMPLOYEE**

```
 |ID (PK) | P_ID |E_ID  |Month   |Capacity|
 |--------|------|------|--------|--------|
 |1       |1     |1     |201701  |0.4     |
 |1       |1     |2     |201701  |0.6     |
 |1       |2     |1     |201701  |0.4     |
```

**EMPLOYEE**

```
 |ID (PK)   | maxCapacity   |
 |----------|---------------|
 |1         | 0.8           |
 |2         | 0.6           |
```

**PROJECT**

```
|ID (PK)   |other columns| 
|----------|-------------|
|1         |some data    | 
|2         |some data    |
```

Furthermore I have a Check Constraint to check wether the combination `(P_ID, E_ID. Month)` of table `PROJECT_EMPLOYEE` is unique.

Now I do not want that someone can insert data into the table `PROJECT_EMPLOYEE`, if the sum of the capacity for an employee in one month is greater than maxCapacity for that specific Employee of Table `EMPLOYEE`.

e.g. in the example above: I should not be able to insert any row for 201701 for Employee 1 nor 2.

Is it prossible to solve this with a check constraint?

Comment: Check constraints deal with individual field values. You'll have to create a trigger or stored procedure that checks the sum and raises an error if the limit is exceeded. Such a trigger though would be *very* costly.

Comment: Such a check also be wrong from a *business perspective*. There's nothing wrong with the *data*. It's the *business* and *application* that have to deal with the very real, very common case where an employee works more than what the business thought he would. By refusing to record the *fact*, you are making a business decision.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos would you recommend to check that at client side?

Comment: I would recommend you talk to the customer first, so you can create a strategy of handling overtime first. Second, if you need to set a maximum *resource* capacity, you *have* to handle this all the way up to the UI level, to prevent people from entering hours that exceed the maximum resource capacity. With employees that maximum capacity would have to be really large to allow people to enter overtime

Comment: I agree, many thanks for your quick and good response. @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: BTW, I have encountered such cases in Project Server implementations. People at a bank would work for more than 8 hours per day, on multiple projects, resulting in weekly hours that looked bad - they exceeded the planned task and project durations, making management look bad. The business owner decided to place a weekly limit resulting in a **HUGE** problem every Friday, as people tried to enter and adjust their hours, then fix their timesheets again and again, escalating all the way to the administrators once the timesheets were closed

Comment: None of these were due to problems or bugs in *Project Server*. They were all business problems. For example, an IT project would serve two or more business units, so IT wantet to "charge" each BU separately. Lacking detailed tasks, they used cost allocations. Overtime and imprecise timesheets resulted in some rather ... interesting cost reports.

Answer (score 1):

A `CHECK` constraint will only be able to check values in the same row - it cannot perform aggregations - so what you are asking is not possible.

Instead you should create a procedure to handle the business logic and revoke permissions to perform direct inserts/updates on the table to ensure that the procedures are used:

```
CREATE PACKAGE PROJECTS_PKG
IS
  PROCEDURE add_Project_Employee(
    project_id  IN  PROJECT_EMPLOYEE.P_ID%TYPE,
    employee_id IN  PROJECT_EMPLOYEE.E_ID%TYPE,
    month       IN  PROJECT_EMPLOYEE.Month%TYPE,
    capacity    IN  PROJECT_EMPLOYEE.Capacity%TYPE,
    status      OUT VARCHAR2
  );
END;
/

CREATE PACKAGE BODY PROJECTS_PKG
IS
  PROCEDURE add_Project_Employee(
    i_project_id  IN  PROJECT_EMPLOYEE.P_ID%TYPE,
    i_employee_id IN  PROJECT_EMPLOYEE.E_ID%TYPE,
    i_month       IN  PROJECT_EMPLOYEE.Month%TYPE,
    i_capacity    IN  PROJECT_EMPLOYEE.Capacity%TYPE,
    o_error       OUT VARCHAR2
  )
  IS
    v_current_capacity PROJECT_EMPLOYEE.Capacity%TYPE;
    v_max_capacity EMPLOYEE.maxCapacity%TYPE;
  BEGIN
    SELECT SUM( capacity )
    INTO   v_current_capacity
    FROM   project_employee
    WHERE  e_id  = i_employee_id
    AND    month = i_month;

    SELECT maxCapacity
    INTO   v_max_capacity
    FROM   employees
    WHERE  e_id = i_employee_id;

    IF v_current_capacity + i_capacity > v_max_capacity THEN
      o_error := 'Max capacity exceeded';
      RETURN;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO PROJECT_EMPLOYEES(
      ID,
      P_ID,
      E_ID,
      Month,
      Capacity,
    ) VALUES (
      PROJECT_EMPLOYEES_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
      i_project_id,
      i_employee_id,
      i_month,
      i_capacity
    );

    o_error := NULL;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      NULL; -- Handle errors
  END;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

One day Oracle [may support SQL assertions](https://community.oracle.com/ideas/13028) that can do this.

Right now [it can be done using a materialized view and a constraint](http://tonyandrews.blogspot.co.uk/2004/10/enforcing-complex-constraints-in.html) like this:

```
create materialized view mv1
build immediate
refresh complete on commit as
select e.maxCapacity, pe.e_id, pe.month, sum(pe.capacity) sumc
  from project_employee pe
       join employee e on e.id = pe.e_id
 group by e.maxCapacity, pe.e_id, pe.month;

alter table mv1
add constraint mv1_chk check (sumc <= maxcapacity);
```

However, this could perform poorly due to the complete refresh. I don't think it can be done with a fast refresh due to the aggregates (though such restrictions change version to version).